# MySQL consistent nonlocking reads vs. INSERT ... SELECT

Tags: mysql, innodb, locking, concurrency, isolation-level

So, from my reading of the MySQL 5.5 documentation and some experiments I did with colleagues, I understand that the following is the case:

1. With InnoDB tables, a simple `SELECT` statement (one that does not use `FOR UPDATE` or `LOCK IN SHARE MODE`) will not grab any row locks on the tables that the `SELECT` statement reads.  This is true at all transaction isolation levels.
2. However, if your transaction isolation level is `REPEATABLE READ` or higher, an `INSERT ... SELECT` or `CREATE TABLE AS SELECT` statement will place row locks on tables that it *reads* from.

Sources:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-consistent-read.html
- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locks-set.html

If I understand this correctly (and correct me if I don't), then I'm puzzled by this difference.  Why does reading a table require lock rows in the one case but not the other, when the transaction isolation level is the same?  I'd like to understand the reason for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-consistent-read.html)

> The type of read varies for selects in clauses like INSERT INTO ... SELECT, UPDATE ... (SELECT), and CREATE TABLE ... SELECT that do not specify FOR UPDATE or LOCK IN SHARE MODE:
>
> By default, InnoDB uses stronger locks and the SELECT part acts like READ COMMITTED, where each consistent read, even within the same transaction, sets and reads its own fresh snapshot.
>
> To use a consistent read in such cases, enable the innodb_locks_unsafe_for_binlog option and set the isolation level of the transaction to READ UNCOMMITTED, READ COMMITTED, or REPEATABLE READ (that is, anything other than SERIALIZABLE). In this case, no locks are set on rows read from the selected table.

Evidently, you do not need stronger locks when just doing reads. Picture copying data into a table using `INSERT ... SELECT` or `CREATE TABLE ... SELECT`. The `SELECT` needs to be a frozen snapshot for loading the table. If it were a moving target, that would require a transaction within a transaction. If you wanted `transaction within a transaction` behavior, you would need to script that using [SAVEPOINT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/savepoint.html). Otherwise, stronger locks allow for consistent SELECTs for an atomic INSERT.

Doing the simple `SELECT` allows your DB Session to trust other transactions not to play [smoke-and-mirrors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smoke_and_mirrors) with your view of the data. If it has to violate that trust, it will politely lock every row it can to do its work, rather than deceive DB Sessions that are only doing SELECTs into thinking the data is stable when it is, in fact, changing.

No matter which [**isolation level**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/dynindex-isolevel.html) you pick, none of them is so granular that a simple SELECT gets held up. That's why [`SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` and `SELECT ... FROM ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-locking-reads.html) were invented, so you can be that granular if politeless is not an option.

I wrote about this before : [How can I make a select statement get blocked?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/41865/how-can-i-make-a-select-statement-get-blocked/41868#41868)

Comment: "The `SELECT` needs to be a frozen snapshot for loading the table. If it were a moving target, that would require a transaction within a transaction." But how is it then that row locks are not needed when you have multiple simple `SELECT`s of the same table within one `REPEATABLE READ` transaction?

Comment: The MVCC within InnoDB would have a virtual snapshot of the data as it appears the moment you read it. Locks are not really needed once the snapshot exists.

Comment: But then why can't `INSERT INTO target SELECT blah FROM source` do the same, and use a transaction-level consistent MVCC snapshot just like the multiple simple `SELECTS` can?  (Assuming no statements in the transaction modify the `source` table.)

Comment: Look at my first paragraph. The SELECT needs to a frozen snapshot. That's the rule imposed by the InnoDB Storage Engine.

Comment: Ok, let me see if I understand it now: when a transaction runs a `INSERT ... SELECT` or `CREATE TABLE AS`, later statements in the same transaction can see these writes. This means that even if the isolation level is `REPEATABLE READ`, the transaction's reads can no longer share the snapshot established by the first read; instead, "the SELECT part acts like READ COMMITTED, where each consistent read, even within the same transaction, sets and reads its own fresh snapshot." So then the engine has to fall back on row locks to preserve the `REPEATABLE READ` semantics, right?

Comment: It does not have `REPEATABLE READ` semantics at all. Look back at the MySQL Document in my answer. It clearly says `InnoDB uses stronger locks and the SELECT part acts like READ COMMITTED`. InnoDB performs internal lock escalation to make `INSERT ... SELECT` possible.