# MySQL INSERT ... SELECT Performance

Tags: mysql, innodb, select, locking

I know that this query will lock `table2`:

```
UPDATE table1... SELECT .. FROM table2
```

How about this query ?

```
INSERT INTO table1... SELECT .. FROM table2
```

Does this query also create a lock on `table2`?

Comment: logically yes if you go for full table scan in select criteria

Comment: It depends, because select doesnt create alock in innodb, bug select for update does

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just asked

> Does:
>
> ```
> INSERT INTO table1... SELECT .. FROM table2
> ```
>
> Also create a lock on table2?

Yes, it does create a lock on `table2`.

I wrote about this behavior back on Aug 08, 2014 (See my answer to [MySQL consistent nonlocking reads vs. INSERT ... SELECT](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/73540/mysql-consistent-nonlocking-reads-vs-insert-select/73542#73542)) In my old post, I mentioned from the MySQL Documentation:

> By default, InnoDB uses stronger locks and the SELECT part acts like READ COMMITTED, where each consistent read, even within the same transaction, sets and reads its own fresh snapshot

Comment: ty ronalando!!! Say, is there anything i can do to prevent the lock in terms of isolation level?